# How to bind a property of inherited class from abstract class

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, data-binding

I have an abstract class with some inherited classes:

```cs
public abstract class Base
{    
    public Base()
    {
    }
}

public class InheritedA : Base
{
    public bool PropertyA { get; set; }

    public InheritedA()
    {
    }
}

public class InheritedB : Base
{
    public bool PropertyB { get; set; }

    public InheritedB()
    {
    }
}
```

How can I bind in the XAML the PropertyA of inherited class when I just have a "Base" class referenced in the datacontext class:

```cs
public class DataContextHere: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Base baseClass{ get; set; }
}
```

Something similar to this?:

```xml
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding baseClass.PropertyA}">
```

Edited Bonus:
And, Is it possible to bind only if the boolean property exists and is true?

```xml
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding baseClass.PropertyA}">
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding baseClass.PropertyB}">
```

In this case, it is checked the first radiobutton if InheritedA is referenced in baseClass, or the second one if InheritedA is referenced.

Thank you

Comment: Your `baseClass` field needs to be a property: `public Base baseClass { get; set; }`. You may also need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. What is `baseClass` a property of? A window, a viewmodel? Please provide much, much, much more detail about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you do, provided that `baseClass` is a *public property* that actually returns an `Inherited` instance:

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding baseClass.PropertyA}">
```

---

```
public Base baseClass { get; } = new Inherited();
```

Comment: This. WPF uses dynamic reflection to for binding. So it doesn't care what instance or what type is bound. As long as it has the property of expected name.